# Orderby if between two meta fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, meta-query, order

I am trying to orderby my CPT if the current time is in between two meta fields. (i.e, the `current_time()` is between two time fields.).

`meta_query` returns only the posts that are between the values, but not all posts. Here is what I have tried.

```
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
        array(
            'key' => 'open_today',
            'value' => strtolower(current_time('l')),
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'open_time',
            'value' => current_time(),
            'compare' => '>='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'close_time',
            'value' => current_time(),
            'compare' => '<'
        ),
    );
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve is that sort restaurants by open time. So, when a user selects to sort the listing by Open Now, the query returns the resturants open now at first and then rest of them.

Comment: Is that `compre` just a typo in the question? Because it should be `compare`..

Comment: I would create 2 queries, one with all the open restaurants, and create an array variable to store all the IDs (call this $exclude_open), and then a second query with the rest of posts using 'post__not_in' => $exclude_open.

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes, its just a typo. Sorry, fixed.

Comment: Okay, but there's another typo there - `current_time()` requires the first parameter. And in your actual `$args`, did you set the [`type` parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/__construct/#parameters)? Because you should, unless if the value is text/char. So if the value is like `07:00` (a time), then you'd use `'type' => 'TIME'`; or if it's a timestamp, you can use `NUMERIC` instead.